# The contrasting meanings of the word "chill"

Tags: meaning, etymology, auto-antonyms

One meaning, the one that I've always known and thought about it when someone said the word "chill", was "very relaxed or easy going" with the example "in general, I am a pretty chill guy", as given  by the definition when you search the word on Google.

However, another definition is "an unpleasant feeling" or even to "horrify or frighten someone", with the example "there was a chill in the air".

Even though the word **chill** in the first example is informal, still I find the 2 definitions in contrast with each other — opposite.

My question is why do we have today this word with two completely different meanings? When did the informal meaning appear? Does it cause some confusion?

Comment: Think of "cool" and "cold".

Comment: First of all, it's being used as a noun in one example and an adjective in another.

Comment: If you are angry then you are steamed, hot under the collar, boiling mad... etc.  So being chill for not being hot makes perfect sense, as does a chill wind, or getting the chills.

Comment: Context. Cool in summer is pleasant; cool in winter is an ordeal. QED. There is **no** contrast in meaning.

Comment: There's probably more danger of confusion with "cool": Saying "he's cool with the idea" means the opposite to "he's cool on the idea". But I can't think of anything so similar with "chill". And note that hot has equivalent ambiguities, with it meaning angry but "being hot on/about something" meaning to be keen on something.

Answer (score 4):

The original sense was used figuratively from the 19th century:

[Chill:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/chill)

> Figurative sense "depressing situation or influence" is from 1821 (in Middle English the figurative sense was "suffering, misfortune").

(Etymonline)

The contemporary sense of relaxed is an AmE  usage from the verbal expression “chill out:”

[Chill out](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/chill-out):

> The idiom chill out means to relax or calm down. This idiom is commonly used in American English.
>
> Chill out became popular in America in the 1970s and functions as a phrasal verb. However, unlike many phrasal verbs, this phrase may be shortened to chill while retaining its idiomatic meaning.

(writingexplained.org)

[Chill:](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/z2untty)

> (orig. US black) 1983 : calm,
> untroubled, relaxed.

(Green’s Dictionary of Slang)